# Detect If Certain Key Was Pressed Twice Rapidly

Tags: c#, xna

I need to check whether or not the "D" or "A" key was pressed twice rapidly, in order for the sprite to change and animate.  Once that key is let go, the sprite should go back to it's original form.  I have a stick figure that once either key is pressed, it should duck down and begin to "roll" in either direction, depending on which key was pressed.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Paul_R** and **Nikola** have actually answered the question for you, but since you said you're new to XNA (read: haven't read all the docs) allow me to introduce some important classes:

We know that a keyboard basically can trigger two types of events: `KeyDown` (on press before release) and `KeyUp` (on release).

A key is pressed when a `KeyDown` event and a `KeyUp` event occur consecutively. I usually store 2 states for this:

```
private KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;
private KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
```

Make sure you also import the necessary package to use these classes.

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
```

Although probably inefficient since you can just have a listener, I update those two states in the main game loop:

```
 protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime){
    previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;
    currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
}
```

If I want to know if a key is pressed, I just call this function:

```
public bool isKeyPressed( Keys key ){
    return previousKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(key) && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(key);
}
```

`Keys` is an *enum*. It contains an enumeration of keyboard keys. For example the letter A in the keyboard is represented by `Keys.A`. The keyboard key PageDown is `Keys.PageDown`. For instance, I want to know if the letter B was pressed, I just call the above method using this statement:

```
isKeyPressed( Keys.B ); //returns true or false
```

Now we know if a key is pressed. This is where your question comes in: how do we know if a key was pressed twice rapidly. You need to define what **rapidly** is. For this example, lets say a rapid press on a key occurs when a key is pressed within 1000 milliseconds after its first press.

Recall that your main game loop receives a parameter `GameTime gameTime.` You can use this, as suggested by **Paul_R**, to get the elapsed time between the previous update and the last update using this statement:

```
elapsedTime = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Noticed that we used the `Milliseconds` property, not the `Seconds`. This is just for consistency's sake. `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds` is the amount of elapsed game time in milliseconds since the last update.

This isn't really an elegant way to do this, but just so you can get the idea, here's a method I made to check if a key was pressed rapidly:

```
public bool isKeyPressedRapidly( Keys key ){
    return isKeyPressed(key) && elapsedTime <= 1000 && lastKeyPressed == key;
}
```

`elapsedTime` is reset everytime `isKeyPressed(key)` returns `true`. Increment `elapsedTime` in the main game loop until another key is pressed. The value of `lastKeyPressed` is, well, the last key you pressed. I'll leave the rest to you. Cheers and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Have a timer that sets a boolean variable to false whenever it fires. Leave this variable set to false and the timer stopped until the user presses a D or A key. Then start the timer. in the timer's tick event handler - set the variable to false and then disable the timer. This way you can set the timer's interval as small as you want. If the user presses A or D, and the boolean variable is already true - then you know that it was pressed recently (within whatever interval you allotted for the timer.) This is just one way of many.

This is nice because it uses built in event handling and will automatically shove it on a background thread so it'll behave asynchronously, and gives you arbitrary control over the allowed interval - you could even build a 'double press sensitivity' setting into the game to adjust this interval.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit new- but how can I set up a timer in XNA?

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark you don't need a timer, just store keypress time in variable and subtract the times

Comment: Well, I didn't realize you're using XNA and therefore are dealing with a compact framework. However, basically all a timer is a variable that increments itself. I believe you can use the following with XNA to return the time since the last update(). Try: `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;`

Comment: It's moments like these that I really feel stupid... I'm still confused, sorry.  Can you perhaps give me an example?

Comment: I can't get the timer to stop...  I reset the time variable to 0, but it continues to go up upon reset.

Comment: That variable is automatically set by the game engine I believe. It'll always keep track of how much has gone by since the last screen update. If you want to have a variable that stays at zero when you reset it , you'll need to make a second variable that you copy the value of gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; into when you want , but then you can reset to zero when you need to. But you can't treat gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds; as a normal variable since the system will alter it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the last pressed key and the time it was pressed

On keypress:

```
1.Check the pressed key and compare with previous (stored in variable)
2.If keys matched then subtract the keypress time from lastpressed and previous pressed key
```

you have to define time in milliseconds to check whether to change sprite and animate

```
3. if the difference in time is less than the defined time then you have to animate
4. Dont forget to set your last pressed key in variable for next keypress comparison
```